# MyBatis Generator stops working after i convert the project to Gradle (STS) or Maven

Tags: gradle, mybatis, mybatis-generator

We are looking into using MyBatis Generator to create our base entities classes and create the CRUD operations

We have created the generatorConfig.xml file and run the MyBatis Generator
In our target folder all classes were created as expected

Now we convert the project to use Gradle (Gradle STS) since this is the convention for all our other projects

once we do that and we re-run the MyBatis Generator we get the following error

"Cannot find source folder for project "

What are we doing wrong?

This is the config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE generatorConfiguration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD MyBatis Generator Configuration 1.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-generator-config_1_0.dtd">
<generatorConfiguration>
  <context id="context1">
    <jdbcConnection connectionURL="jdbc:sqlserver://<>.database.windows.net:1433;database=dbName;user=dbUser;password=password" driverClass="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" password="...." userId="...." />
    <javaModelGenerator targetPackage="javaModelGenerator" targetProject="myBatisArt\src"  />
    <sqlMapGenerator targetPackage="sqlMapGenerator" targetProject="myBatisArt\src" />
    <javaClientGenerator targetPackage="javaClientGenerator" targetProject="myBatisArt\src" type="XMLMAPPER" />
    <table catalog="myDB" tableName="Companies">      
    </table>   
  </context>
</generatorConfiguration>
```

I created the Java project "myBatisArt"

On first run , all files were created OK.

Then when hitting "Configure-->Convert to Gradle (STS) Project

(see image)

and running the generation process again i get the error

"Cannot find source folder for project"

[image]

Comment: How are you running the generator in Gradle?  Might help to show the relevant section of your build file.

Comment: How on earth could we know what you're doing wrong without showing us what you're doing?

Comment: i am running the generation process from within eclipse. "Gradle" is added to the target Java project and not to the project where i have the Generation script

Comment: I'm guessing that when you changed the project to a gradle project, it altered the structure of the source directories.  Perhaps the source directory is now something like "src/main/java", and therefore your generator configuration file needs to change and have targetProject look like "myBatisArt\src\main\java".

Comment: The STS Gradle Plugin is legacy, you should be using [buildship](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship) for gradle integration in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Tried to alter the targetProject property to myBatisArt\src\main\java as suggested. but this did not help.

On the other hand the src folder was not defined as a "src" folder in eclipse.

When i went to Properties=>Java Build Path=>Source and added "src" folder it solved the problem

Now i can run "MyBatis Generator" and i get no error.

But, on the third hand, when i refresh the STS project , the src folder is no longer defined as a "src" folder again and i have to re-define it.

I guess that , as Lance said, since STS is legacy I have these problems.